# WordPress - creating microsites

Tags: wordpress

I have never used WordPress before but it seems to be the best package for user content sites.

I need to have a main site which has its own content but also be able to spawn microsites for a particular event.

These microsites will have around 10 pages and will use the same template and will need to have their content changeable.

In terms of url it would probably look a bit like this

main site - www.blog-x.com

microsite - www.blog-x.com/march-meetup/join

microsite page - www.blog-x.com/march-meetup/contact

Is this possible with WordPress ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're talking about is simply adding Pages - not creating microsites.  To get the URLs you want, all you'd have to do is create a new Page. (or even better, just create a category for each section, and post the relevant info to that category).

In other words, yes, it'll do what you want - but calling it a "microsite" is a misnomer.

Answer (score 6):

If you by "use the same template" mean that the "microsites" should use the same layout and look like the main site, then see Shelly's answer above.

However, if you mean that you want these "microsites" to have different templates (but that the microsites' pages should use the same template), you're looking for the multi-site feature of WordPress. It will allow you to create new blogs (sites) in either subdirectories (blog-x.com/march-meetup) or on subdomains (march-meetup.blog-x.com). See [WordPress Codex: Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) for details.